# Microsoft Fakes Assembly name conflict

Tags: c#, testing, microsoft-fakes

I have 3 C# projects X, Y and Z. I have 2 unit test projects Xt that tests code in project X, and Yt that tests code in project Y. Project Z is a library project and is referenced by projects X and Y.

In both unit tests project I have generated a Fakes assembly for Z, meaning they both have their own version of Z.Fakes.dll. All DLLs are outputted into the same directory. Because they both create a Z.Fakes.dll, one overwrites the other in the output directory, depending on the build order, meaning one set of unit tests fails because the Shims & Stubs do no exist in the fakes assembly.

Assuming that I can't set different output directories for each unit test project, and cannot merge the unit tests into a single unit test project, how can I avoid this Fakes assembly name conflict? Is there any way to generate a Fakes Assembly and give it an alias e.g. Zx.Fakes.dll and Zy.Fakes.dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we are handling it is we have a separate Fakes project in the solution that you generate all of your fakes in, you then just add the dlls in the `FakesAssemblies` folder in that fakes project. When you do that your solution reference structure should look like this

```
Solution
- MyFakes
  - References
    - X
    - X.Fakes //Created via the right-click create Fake menu on X
    - Y
    - Y.Fakes //Created via the right-click create Fake menu on Y
    - Z
    - Z.Fakes //Created via the right-click create Fake menu on Z
- X.csproj
  - References
    - Z
- Xt.csproj
  - References
    - MyFakes //This is just for build order
    - X
    - ..\MyFakes\FakesAssemblies\X.Fakes.dll
    - Z
    - ..\MyFakes\FakesAssemblies\Z.Fakes.dll
- Y.csproj
  - References
    - Z
- Yt.csproj
  - References
    - MyFakes //This is just for build order
    - Y
    - ..\MyFakes\FakesAssemblies\Y.Fakes.dll
    - Z
    - ..\MyFakes\FakesAssemblies\Z.Fakes.dll
- Z.csproj
```